# Why doesn't the config for plotly doesn't work in dash?

Tags: plotly-dash

When I use `fig.show`, the mode bar buttons do show up but then when I try to do the same with dash, it doesn't work. I tried so many options and it just doesn't seem to work. The documentation is incomplete as well. These are the inbuilt buttons by the way, not custom.

I saw this in a tutorial:

```py
fig.show(config={'modeBarButtonsToAdd':['drawline',
                                        'drawopenpath',
                                        'drawclosedpath',
                                        'drawcircle',
                                        'drawrect',
                                        'eraseshape'
                                       ]})
```

Then, I tried to put the same in dash instead of `fig.show`, but it wouldn't work!

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='mainPlot',
        figure=fig,
        config={'modeBarButtonsToAdd':['drawline',
                                        'drawopenpath',
                                        'drawclosedpath',
                                        'drawcircle',
                                        'drawrect',
                                        'eraseshape'
                                       ]}
    )
])
```

Here is the MWE: I want to pass the `config` with `modeBarButtonsToAdd` through `config` via the `app.layout` and not `fig.show`. It works with `fig.show` as the buttons are inbuilt but doesn't work with the `app.layout` config pass as I get errors that say the buttons need to be defined with name, click functionality, etc. and are being treated as custom buttons as opposed to enabling inbuilt buttons.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: To make it easier to help, please add a MWE that runs. In the current code the fig object is missing.

Comment: @emher I added the MWE as requested...sorry for not adding it earlier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest version of dash should fix your issue.